# Is there a way to enable Windows 10's battery saver permanently?

Tags: windows, windows-10, battery, battery-life, telemetry

This may be a silly question, but is there a way to enable Windows 10's battery saver while connected to a power source?

My computer has a old hard disk, and Windows is much faster with the power saver enabled, because Telemetry and other background processes, which use a lot of resources, are disabled. I know some, like Microsoft Update are actually useful, but sometimes I just want use the computer, and not wait like half an hour until it is finally kinda usable.

(I am sorry for my terrible English, not a native.)
(And yes, I could just disable telemetry, but I am curious if this is possible.)